# Cell after scroll show image over image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

I have tableview and I want to show all images from one folder inside directory and I have path to that directory. I am loading image to cell like:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    for (UIView * view in cell.contentView.subviews){
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    cell.imageView.image = nil;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:absoluteImagePath];
    UIImage *thumbNail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumbNail];            
    [cell insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
}
```

but when I scroll up and down I get image over image inside cell (old image is visible below new, when I scroll on for example first position I see image for index 0 below other image ).
Does anyone know what is a problem, I am new to this iOS programming ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should

- subclass your cell,
- create an outlet for the image, and
- design the layout in storyboard.

The benefits:

- No need to check for `(cell==nil)`
- You will have to write less code
- Cleaner solution without redundant view creation errors

Comment: Alternatively, you can just use `imageView` property of `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: @RinatKhanov Yes, but OP will have less (presumably not sufficient) control over the look and positioning of the image view.

Answer (score 1):

When the cell is reused, `[cell insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];` adds an additional `UIImageView` to the cell. Suggestion is to create a custom `UITableViewCell` and in the `prepareForReuse` method, remove the `UIImageView`. An easy way to identify `UIImageView` to remove is to add a `tag` to it. E.g.,

`imageView.tag = 1000;`

Then you can find the image view with

```
UIImageView *imageView = [self.contentView viewWithTag:1000];
if (imageView) {
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the UIImageView where you are initializing the cell. 
For example

```
if (cell==nil)
{ 
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:yourFrame];
[cell addSubView:image];
}
image.image = yourImage;
```

Alternatively, you can remove all subviews from the cell before adding new UIImageView as subview.

Comment: If cell is nil to add subview ? To nil object ?

Comment: Yes, just try it and it will work. Or you can subclass UITableViewCell as mundi said.